# Switching from Ubuntu to Windows 7 help?

Tags: windows-7

I switched from windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS a week or so ago on my Toshiba Satellite L755 I believe. It worked fine, but I had Internet problems and internal errors so I thought switching to 12.10 would fix everything, I was wrong.

Long story short, I want to switch back to windows 7 but when I installed over windows 7. I don't have a recovery CD because, can I create a recovery CD on another computer and use that?

Thanks Terry and everyone else who answered!  I was able to restore my computer using a back up from when I had Windows 7 so if all goes well I'll be set.

Comment: You likely need for get a Windows ISO and call microsoft and read off the key from the label on the laptop in order to get it activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options (Not all will work for you depending on your situation, but at least a couple should work.).

1. You can go to Toshiba's support page and buy a recovery disk: https://support.toshiba.com/repair
2. You can use your recovery partition by selecting F1, F8, etc. when booting (see "Free options: on the Toshiba support website link.
3. You may also borrow an OEM version of Windows from a friend (with the exact same version as your computer). Enter in your product key when installing (usually on the bottom of the computer).
4. Follow the instructions here: [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-reinstall-windows?lq=1)
5. Stay with Ubuntu! (Just saying it is a good choice too :-) )

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I made a system repair disc but I don't know where to go from there, any help? I put the disc in, made sure my computer boots from disc but I just get a menu with 3 options

Comment: What do your options look like?

Comment: Just a minute, I'm switching back to 12.04 so I can actually access my computer and not have a stuck mouse

Comment: Okay, those 3 options were just to run ubuntu, it was ubuntu and two others but it wasn't for the repair disc. How do I my disc? Sorry if I'm asking very mundane questions, but your help is very appreciated

Comment: Ok, this recovery disk, is this an Ubuntu recovery or windows recover disc? It sounds like you are seeing the grub boot menu (which is a linux thing)... If this is a windows disc, you need to log into your BIOS and make sure the boot order is CD-ROM first. To log in to BIOS, repeatedly press F12 as the computer is starting.

Answer (score 0):

most likely, your laptop had a recovery partition for Win7 OEM version on the hard drive already, use *gparted* and see if it still exists.

If it does then usually (for my aspire one) F12 at memtest/clock screen opens the recovery for windows.

If not then you will more likely need to borrow a CD and reformat your harddrive to boot.
hopefully you have kept your OEM cdkey somewhere (ie underside of the laptop)

Dont give up on ubuntu though, I recently switched from vista, after a bit of tweaking (more so than on a windows OS) i found that im much much happier with an OS i can completely reconfigure what i want, when i want to, at half the boot time.

If you can give a more detailed description of your internal errors I guarantee that this community can help. I've relied on it so much during my first month with 13.10 but im starting to get the hang of it now